# How to convert multiple imputation data to mids in r?

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I used another program to impute missings in my data

.imp is coded as X_mult_ in csv file

After converting X_mult_ column into .imp and making .id column, I tried as.mids() function but r says "Original data is not found."

So I tried again with this code, but R says "replacement has 26 rows, data has 27" which means there is still NA in db

But how can I incorporate original data without NA?

Please help me...

```
org <- read.csv("Final_Study_Subject.csv", header=T)
fss <- read.csv("Final_Study_Subject_IMPUTE.csv", header=T)

org$.imp <- rep(0, 2546)
fss$.imp <- fss$X_mult_
fss<- fss[,-c(25)]
str(org)
a<-rbind(org, fss)

str(a)

a$ID <- as.numeric(a$ID)
a$.id <- a$ID
a <- a[,-c(1)]
a <- a[, c(32,33,1:31)]
str(a)

c <-as.mids(a)
```